# Azul Prime JVM in Container, GC huge times when compared to OpenJDK while using Apache Spark on K8s cluster

Tags: performance, apache-spark, kubernetes, jvm, garbage-collection

I having a small java application written in Apache Spark and running it on k8s cluster.

I started with OpenJDK - JVM  (17) and then setup the same for AzulPrime-JVM (17) [azul prime docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/azul/prime)

I was expecting to have overall lower latency in my GC times and overall better execution time, when comparing to openJDK, but actually the times of GC on AzulPrime JVM - are much higher like 10 times higher than OpenJDK.

---

- Did anyone experience similar issue with GC as far as using AzulPrime in Containers ?
- Did you have any tips, what I can try to get better results on AzulPrime while using it ?

I expect lower GC latencies when using Azul prime in docker container while using apache spark on k8s cluster. I tried to run my Apache spark with different extra jvm options, and also using defaults, but without success.